# load data into SQL while datatype and column width in sas code?

Tags: sql, sas

Hi I'm trying to load [this data](https://www.cms.gov/apps/ama/license.asp?file=http://download.cms.gov/Research-Statistics-Data-and-Systems/Statistics-Trends-and-Reports/Medicare-Provider-Charge-Data/Downloads/Medicare_Provider_Util_Payment_PUF_CY2014.zip) into mySQL server. It's a 2 Gb txt file, and the delimiter is tab.

I can use import data wizard, and choose file type `Flat File Source` to import it. But in this way I additionally need to tell the database about the datatype and length of each column.

Information about the datatype and length of each column is available in sas-infile code (downloaded together with the data). (I replaced code of many columns with `....` for conciseness)

```
DATA Medicare_PS_PUF;
    LENGTH
        npi                                 $ 10
        nppes_provider_last_org_name        $ 70
        nppes_provider_first_name           $ 20
        nppes_provider_mi                   $ 1
        ....
        average_Medicare_standard_amt       8;
    INFILE 'C:\My Documents\Medicare_Provider_Util_Payment_PUF_CY2014.TXT'

        lrecl=32767
        dlm='09'x
        pad missover
        firstobs = 3
        dsd;

    INPUT
        npi             
        nppes_provider_last_org_name 
        nppes_provider_first_name 
        nppes_provider_mi 
        ....
        average_Medicare_standard_amt;
RUN;
```

I think maybe I should use the sas-infile code to load txt file into sas, and save it as sas-format data, and then import the sas-format data into mySQL.

My question is, can the info of datatype and length of each column be passed from SAS into mySQL ?

Any suggestion/other methods to handle this is appreciated. Thanks-

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to first submit a `describe table` query in `proc sql`. For example:

```
proc sql;
  describe table sashelp.class;
quit;
```

SAS Log shows:

```
create table SASHELP.CLASS( label='Student Data' bufsize=65536 )
  (
   Name char(8),
   Sex char(1),
   Age num,
   Height num,
   Weight num
  );
```

This will need to be adapted to MySQL's syntax -- labels removed, `char` may become `varchar`, `num` becomes `int` or `float`, and so on.

Then you could try inserting the data into the newly created MySQL table. Either by point-and-click through your MySQL interface, or if this is not possible, by generating a text file from SAS containing a series of `insert into` queries (using a `file` statement in a data step with the `put` statement to generate the appropriate queries), and then submitting this text file to your MySQL database.

Quick example (not tested):

```
data _null_;
  file 'insert_queries.sql';
  set sashelp.class;
  query = "insert into class values ("||
          catx(",", quote(trim(Name)), quote(Sex), Height, Weight)||
          ");";
  put query;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the right SAS/Access modules licensed you can copy the data directly from SAS to MySQL.

But it sounds like you are asking how to convert the SAS code into metadata about the table structure.  I would recommend running the program in SAS to create the `Medicare_PS_PUF` dataset and then using `PROC CONTENTS` to get the metadata about the variables. You can add `OBS=0` to the `INFILE` statement if you just want to create an empty dataset in SAS.